# <#assign x=${size}> it does not give the right result

Tags: java, concatenation, freemarker

```
<#assign x=${size}>
```

in ftl file above code does not give x the value of the size template from java fikle, how can i get the value of size equal to my variable x?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `${}` there.

Just write `<#assign x = size>`.